# Optimising drawing graphs from a model: code architecture

Tags: python, matplotlib, architecture

OK, I have a question about how to lay out code efficiently.

I have a model written in python which generates results which I use to produce graphs in matplotlib. As written, the model is contained within a single file, and I have 15 other run-files, which call on it with complicated configurations and produce graphs. It takes a while to go through and run each of these run-files, but since they all use substantially different settings for the model, I need to have complicated setup files anyway, and it all works.

I have the output set up for figures which could go in an academic paper. I have now realised that I am going to need each of these figures again in other formats - one for presentations (low dpi, medium size, different font) and one for a poster (high dpi, much bigger, different font again.)

This means I could potentially have 45 odd files to wade through every time I want to make a change to my model. I also would have to cut and paste a lot of boilerplate matplotlib code with minor alterations (each run-file would become 3 different files - one for each graph).

Can anybody explain to me how (and if) I could speed things up? At the moment, I think it's taking me much longer than it should.

As I see it there are 3 main options:

1. Set up 3 run-files for each actual model run (so duplicate a fair amount, and run the model a lot more than I need) but I can then tweak everything independently (but risk missing something important).
2. Add another layer - so save the results as .csv or equivalent and then read them into the files for producing graphs. This means more files, but I only have to run the model once per 3 graphs (which might save some time).
3. Keep the graph and model parameter files integrated, but add another file which sets up graphing templates, so every time I run the file it spits out 3 graphs) It might speed things up a bit, and will certainly keep the number of files down, but they will get very big (and probably much more complicated).
4. Something else..

Can anybody point me to a resource or provide me with some advice on how best to handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are close to find what you want.

If calculations take some time, store results in files to process later without recalculation.

The most important: separate code from configuration, instead of copy pasting variations of such mixture.

If the model takes parameters, define a model class. Maybe instantiate the model only once, but the model knows how to `load_config`, `read_input_data` and `run`. Model also does `write_results`. That way you can loop a sequence of `load_config`, `read_data`, `write_results` for every config and maybe input data.

Write the config files by hand with ini format for example and use the `confiparser` module to load them.

Do something similar for your `Graph` class. Put the template definition in configuration files, including output format, sizes fonts, and so on.

In the end you will be able to "manage" the intended workflow with a single script that uses this facilites. Maybe store groups of related configuration files, output templates and input data together, one group per folder for each modelling session.

Comment: Thanks, I know it's a fairly woolly question, but the general shape of the thing was really confusing me.